# Turning assembly instruction into hex using C

Tags: c, mips

I'm trying to make a baby assembler essentially using C. I have it reading in the instructions fine, but I'm struggling with taking the instruction and properly converting it into hex. How can I take multiple decimal values and put them together into a 32 bit binary number to convert to hex?

Here is what I have now for the instruction `addi $t0,$t1,10`:

```
opcode = opcode >> 2;
rs = rs >> 1;
rt = rt >>1;
imm = imm >> 15;
printf("0x%X:\t0x%X%X%X%X",list[i].a,opcode,rs,rt,imm);
```

Comment: for displaying?

Comment: Yes. It would print out the hex instruction format to standard output.

Answer (score 1):

First or(`|`) it into one number. For example and this is for sure wrong. Just to get the idea.

```
int hex = (opcode<<24)|(rs<<16)|(rt<<8)|(imm);
```

Then:

```
printf("0x%X:\t0%X",list[i].a, hex);
```

Comment: This is what I was thinking. However, addi has an opcode of eight, but the field for the opcode in the binary representation of the whole thing is six bits. How would I shift it while preserving the two leading zeros in that case?

Comment: @CameronFuruseth: the *value* `8` fits into 6 bits -- with plenty of room to spare. Shifting a bit value doesn't need "preserving" of zero bits. If this answer doesn't work for that instruction, better add it to your question.